# Do pyd files only work against the linked python version?

Tags: python, pyd

I compiled [SimpleElastix](https://github.com/SuperElastix/SimpleElastix) for both Windows and Linux months ago. The SimpleElastix build process produced a `.so` file under Linux and a `.pyd` under Windows for use with Python. I was able to `import SimpleElastix` under python 3.6 in both Linux and Windows and use the library, no problem.

Fast forward to now. I've upgraded to python 3.10. I am still able to `import SimpleElastix` under Linux using the same `.so`, but I cannot do the same under Windows. Python 3.10 cannot find the `.pyd` file no matter what I do. I tried adding the location to `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, and even `os.add_dll_directory`. I'm pretty sure if I simply re-built `SimpleElastix` with Python 3.10 in my PATH, it would probably work. The only trouble is, the project seems semi dead and the [build process is currently broken](https://github.com/SuperElastix/SimpleElastix/issues/489) due to unpinned dependencies.

My question is: Are pyd files only importable against a single specific python version (the one it was linked against)? It seems so since examples I read online for creating pyd files involve passing i.e. `-lpython36` to the compiler. Is there a way to build pyd files like Linux .so files that don't have that limitation? Is there a way to "relink" a .pyd against a newer python version without access to the original build?

Comment: libpython reserves the right to make ABI-incompatible changes between minor releases; only point-releases are guaranteed to retain ABI compatibility.

Comment: Do you know why .pyd files need to be linked against libpython but .so files do not?

Comment: ...to be clear about how one can retain API compatibility but break ABI compatibility, think about renaming a function but creating a preprocessor directive to redirect calls to the old name to use the new one; code will still compile, but it _has_ to be recompiled; relinking will fail. That's even more true if you're doing things like extending a struct to add more members (changing its size), or adding new arguments to a function (changing the stack layout used when calling it) while having the preprocessor paper over the changes, etc.

Comment: Eh? Many .so files _do_ link against libpython. Depends on the details of the individual project -- if you're using ctypes, f/e, then it's native Python code responsible for knowing how to bridge the gap.

Comment: Just because they do doesn't mean they must, correct? Looks like you can compile a `.so` with `-fPIC` etc and the resulting library is importable by python. But it appears you cannot do the same with pyd

Comment: (...in all honesty, I grok .so files a lot more than I do .pyd; I'm a Unix developer, not a Windows person)

Comment: `.so` isn't Python-specific at all, and the whole point of ctypes is to use arbitrary C libraries from Python. Now, is there a format for C modules written in Python that _is_ Python-specific and version-dependent? Yes, absolutely. But not every `.so` used from Python is in that format. (Similarly, on Windows you can use ctypes to link to functions in a DLL that doesn't itself link to libpython)

Comment: On the other hand, .so files used from Python _in the same way as .pyd files_ **are** in the aforementioned version-specific format (compiled against a given release's headers), and attempting to use them from different Python releases from the one they were compiled against is not supported. So if you're asserting that you can take a Python C module from Python 3.5 and load it from Python 3.6... that's very much not supported.